Excel formula - returning a list of values from multiple criteria
I’ve had a real struggle with this one and can’t crack it for the life of me.
I need to create an excel formula that does the following:
*Looks for all Values in Forces!A1:A5000 that match the value in Battles!G1
*As well as looking for all values in Forces!E1:E5000 that match the value in Battles!A1.
*For all correct matches for both Battles!G1 and Battles!A1, the formula must return the value located in the same row for Forces!D1:D5000 and produce a list of the results in a column of cells, not as a text list.
Is there anyone that could help with that?

There is no sample data given, hence on assumption, you could try: =FILTER(Forces!D1:D5000,(Forces!A1:A5000=Battles!G1)*(Forces!E1:E5000=Battles!A1),"Not Found")

That's perfect, it did the trick perfectly, thank you so much.

Try using FILTER() function:
=FILTER(Forces!D1:D5000,(Forces!A1:A5000=Battles!G1)*(Forces!E1:E5000=Battles!A1),"Not Found")



Condition One: Match all the Battles!G1 with the range Forces!A1:A5000
Condition Two: Match all the Battles!A1 with the range Forces!E1:E5000
When the conditions matches return the output using FILTER() to include all those are TRUE from range Forces!D1:D5000


